# SSAS - How to import translations (dimensions / measure, etc) in Excel ?

Tags: sql-server, excel, sql-server-2012, ssas, powerpivot

I'm creating an SSAS cube and I would like to provide friendly names for dimensions, measures, KPIs etc.. So, I created all transactions for all properties in Visual Studio Data Tools.

When I browse my cube in Visual Studio it works well, all properties are translated.
However, if I launch PowerPivot for Excel and trying to import data, no property is translated, It gives me strange names such as [Dimension Name] [Hierachy Name] etc.

Any idea to provide friendly translaed names in Excel ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

1. On the Table Import Wizard, where you setup your connection to the SSAS click Advanced.
2. Change the Locale Identifier setting to the preferred locale.

You can find the  locale Ids [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/nb-no/goglobal/bb964664.aspx), in order to find the Id of the language you used at the translations you made at the cube.

[image]

Comment: When I use the import wizard from Excel, measures as well as dimensions are correctly translated in french. However, after importing data all columns names are the specified raw name, not the french translation. For example if I create a measure entitled "Margin" and adding the "Marge" translation for french, it displays me "Marge" in the import wizard but "margin" in the PowerPivot table after import. And I need to manualy rename all columns. That's scaring me ! It annoys me (: ! I tried you suggestion but the result is the same, french language during the import but default one after.

Comment: I think specifying a locale identifier should be usefull if I want to browse the import wizard in another language than the configured language in Excel.

Comment: There is also a specific language option for PowerPivot plugin. It can be found at the powerpivot ribbon under Settings. Have you checked that you have french selected there too?

Comment: Unfortunately, it's configured as "Use the same language than Excel" for Language Option and as "French(France)" for Language and Model Language. I tried to force the first one to French (France) but there is no change :/

Comment: This problem is not resolved at all. Can it be a SSAS default language issue ? I see it's possible to specify the SSAS language through SQL Server Management Studio. Or perhaps I did a mistake. In my SSAS project (tranlations ribbon), in the first column (default) I wrote all names in English then I created a French translation. Is it good ?